# Less or sass imprementation in existing project and collaborating with programers who don't use sass/less

Tags: css, sass, less

Okey! i recently came up with learning sass/less and it was quit interesting and i totally love to implement them. Now real question is how can i implement in preexisting project that is done in css. I know css is pretty backward compatible. but i don't want to force all the project-member to use less.

If anyone update the css file, will it be ported to less file automatically i don't know for sure!!

will there be any issue or problem to implement less on existing project??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the full benefits of Sass/less you'd want to refactor the existing style sheet(s) to take advantage of @mixin and @include (and @extend in Sass) and unless everyone on the team was onboard, or you're committed to integrating their commits, I wouldn't bother. Writing styles in meta-languages like Sass/Less changes the way you think about styling -- it really is a different mindset. That said, I really don't think it's too much to ask that other team members adopt a more modern approach and I've had good luck with that on projects. The key I think is doing the infrastructure work and initial hand-holding to make it easy for them. Write some useful mixins that save them time. Try to anticipate their needs.  I find I have to still do some refactoring, but as time goes by it becomes less (no pun intended) of a chore.

Comment: i appreciate your answer, that solves/answers large part of question and i'm just curious if i could implement less bothering no one, all other programmer could do little css they know in their own way and somehow i could go on with less. without making any conflicts..

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem in?

Just allocate some css code you will support yourself into separate file.
I did it while converting big project css to less and then less to sass

You can even make some preproccessed css in SASS and in Less but i think it's not good for maintence)

Well, i don't know how are you going to use i'll describe you may experience. First choose choose tools for converting precss code. I'm using Visual Studio addin Midscape Web Workbench. It allows me to update css file(sass in free edition, less only in pro edition as i remember) on save.

And first of all you just rename all you *.css files to *.less and it will generate same css files as you had before. Then you can start to optimaze plain css one file to another and the main point that less/sass code and plain css can be in the same file.

Comment: i'm confuse on if any programmer add some code in plain css file will it synchronize to my less file or not? actually large part of my job is fixing css bug so i don't know for sure is it good for me. anyway thanks for responding

Comment: I've updated answer, maybe my words aren't clear, feel free to ask if you still have questions